# Silent install APK programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-install-apk

Sorry for my poor English. I want to figure out how to install (or delete) APK file silently without root programmatically.

First of all I added `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` to manifest, and permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
```

Code of installing and deleting

```
    public void installApp(File file){
        try {
            final String command = "pm install " + file.getPath();
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {command });
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void deleteApp(String appPackage){
        try {
            final String command = "pm uninstall " + appPackage;
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {command });
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And as I know I need manufacturer keys to sign my App. I didn't found keys for Android Studio emulators, so for example I downloaded an image of Android 4.4 r2 from here http://www.android-x86.org/releases/releasenote-4-4-r2 (and mount it in Oracle VM) and got keys from here https://sourceforge.net/p/android-x86/build/ci/android-x86-4.4-r2/tree/target/product/security/ .As I understood `platform.x509.pem` and `platform.pk8` are keys what I needed.

I signed my App with `signapk.jar` something like this `java -jar signapk.jar platform.x509.pem platform.pk8 app.apk signapp.apk`.

But it doesn't work. Some of attempts ended with error:

Uninstall

```
07-30 04:42:46.050 1477-1477/com.jinga.jihome W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [pm uninstall ru.bogdanov.mom] Working Directory: null Environment: null
        at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
07-30 04:42:46.060 1477-1477/com.jinga.jihome W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:173)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:128)
        at com.jinga.jihome.updater.packageInstaller.PackageInstallerHelper.deleteApp(PackageInstallerHelper.java:59)
        at com.jinga.jihome.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:102)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-30 04:42:46.070 1477-1477/com.jinga.jihome W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
```

Install

```
07-30 04:42:49.420 1477-1477/com.jinga.jihome W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [pm install /storage/sdcard/app-debug.apk] Working Directory: null Environment: null
        at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:173)
07-30 04:42:49.430 1477-1477/com.jinga.jihome W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:128)
        at com.jinga.jihome.updater.packageInstaller.PackageInstallerHelper.installApp(PackageInstallerHelper.java:49)
        at com.jinga.jihome.MainActivity$2.onSuccess(MainActivity.java:135)
        at com.jinga.jihome.MainActivity$2.onSuccess(MainActivity.java:126)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn$ObserveOnSingleObserver.run(SingleObserveOn.java:81)
        at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
```

Some of signed apks doesn't want to install with error like `App conflicts with existing package by the same name`or what my device not incompatible for this Apk, but without signing all ok.

I've tried with different images, key pairs and emulators, but not succeed, what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I too have an app which installs and updates apks on client devices.

It is also signed with the platform signing keys which means we have permission to install this on their players!

On Android 8.x I've had to set

> android:sharedUserId="android.uid.shell"

in the  to make it work.  I'm using the command:

`File localApk = new File("apkName.apk");
String[] Commands = {"pm", "install", "-r", localApk.getAbsolutePath()};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Commands);`

Without the shareUserId being set I always got permission errors.

Answer (score 1):

Permissions defined in app's manifest have nothing to do with shell commands. They guard the Java API.

`DELETE_PACKAGES` permission guards the `PackageManager#deletePackage` method. It's not part of the public SDK so you'll have to access it using reflection (or compile your app against [unhidden android.jar](https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api)).

#### The reflection path

You'll need to copy this interface to your project:

```
package android.content.pm;

interface IPackageDeleteObserver {
    void packageDeleted(String packageName, int returnCode);
}
```

Then call the `deletePackage` method using reflection. Here's a sample in Kotlin:

```
private val deletePackageMethod = PackageManager::class.java.getDeclaredMethod(
    "deletePackage",
    String::class.java,
    IPackageDeleteObserver::class.java,
    Int::class.javaPrimitiveType
)

@RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES)
fun PackageManager.deletePackage(
    packageName: String,
    observer: IPackageDeleteObserver,
    flags: Int
) {
    deletePackageMethod.invoke(this, packageName, observer, flags)
}
```

You can find the flags and return codes in [`PackageManager` source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java) as constants prefixed with `DELETE_`.

So far this is all tested and verified.

**Notes:** Reflection is extra work, so we do the method lookup only once. The method is hidden but public so you don't need to call `setAccessible(true)`.

**Warning:** Please test this on Android 9, I can't guarantee this works with the ban on accessing hidden API. I think since your app is signed with the system signature *and* runs as the `system` user, it *should* have no problem.

#### The unhide path

If you compile against the modified android.jar you can directly reference types mentioned above.

The only problem I encountered was that gradle task `mockableAndroidJar` is not compatible with modified android.jar. You'll have to exclude that task from execution by adding `-x mockableAndroidJar` to gradle command line in the IDE.

I haven't actually tried it, I can't tell you if the IDE will let you any further.